# Android - Overriding theme.xml styling

Tags: android

I have global style defined in the theme.xml file. This includes the item `<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>`.

I have a DatePicker which selected-date background uses this style-item and thus is white... on white background. The selected date is therefore invisible.

This is the DatePicker:

```
<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
    style="@style/date_picker_theme"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:calendarViewShown="false"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:endYear="2100"
    android:startYear="1900" />
```

and I tried to override the `colorControlActivated` style (in the styles.xml) like that:

```
<style name="date_picker_theme">
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>
</style>
```

but that doesn't reflect at all.

If I change the theme.xml style-item to `<item name="colorControlActivated">@color/green</item>` then it reflects fine, but might change some other styling throughout the app.

**Question**: How can I override this only for my DatePicker?

**How it looks now**:

[image]

**How it should look**:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting it as

```
style="@style/date_picker_theme"
```

set it as

```
android:theme="@style/date_picker_theme"
```

Full Datepicker view below

```
<DatePicker
  android:id="@+id/DatePicker"
  android:theme="@style/date_picker_theme"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  android:calendarViewShown="false"
  android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
  android:endYear="2100"
  android:startYear="1900" />
```